# Dynamic Dropdown Selections in CodeIgniter with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 HTML dropdowns. The first dropdown is static and the next two are dependent on the previous dropdown. My view looks like this:

```
                   <div class="col-xs-3">
                          <label for="cat1"><h4>Main Category</h4></label>
                          <select class="form-control" name="cat1" id="cat1"
                           onchange="$('#secondary').load('<?php echo site_url('createplay/getMainCategories'); ?>?cat='+this.value);">
                            <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT level_one FROM categories";
                            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
                            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                              echo "<option value='".$row->level_one."'>".$row->level_one."</option>";
                            }
                             ?>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-4" id='secondary'>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-xs-3" id='sub-secondary'>
                      </div>
```

The SQL is only in the view to help you understand what it is I am doing. I normally keep it in the model. The `onchange` calls a controller/method and passes the HTML `select` value to it. Here is `getMainCategories`:

```
public function getMainCategories() {
    $cat = $this->input->get('cat');
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT level_two FROM categories WHERE level_one='".$cat."'";
    echo '<label for="cat2"><h4>Secondary Category</h4></label>';

    $jquery = "$('#sub-secondary').load('".site_url('createplay/getSubSecondary')."?subcat='+this.value);";

    echo  '<select class="form-control" name="cat2" id="cat2" 
            onchange="'.$jquery.'">';

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        echo  '<option value="'.$row->level_two.'">'.$row->level_two.'</option>';
    }

    echo   '</select>';
}
```

Now the first dropdown shows correctly, and when I make a selection the second dropdown appears and works correctly. The problem is when I make the selection in the second dropdown the third dropdown does not appear. Nothing happens, no error messages, nothing. I am sure it is because of the way I am calling the jQuery from the PHP script.

How can I fix this to make it cleaner and make the 3rd dropdown populate?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is, get selected value from first dropdown and pass it to controller (use `onchange` event in jquery). And in ajax response put new dropdown menu which will be the result of that controller.

Something like this:

CONTROLLER:

```
$data['second_drop_down_data'] = // This will be the result of your
                                 // selected value from first drop down...
echo $this->load->view->('second_drop_down', $data, TRUE);
```

You can apply same logic for third and forth dropdown menu...

Comment: I have your method working  but I still don't get how to call the third dropdown.

Comment: Where are you putting your second ajax function? It should be in this view-> `second_drop_down`, not in your main file

Comment: Right now I have 3 views (the main view with static dropdown, a view with the HTML for Second Dropdown and a view for the third dropdown.) I have the ajax .load call in each view

Answer (score 0):

I think reason behind no response is in your "getMainCategories" function. Just check below line in your code:

```
$jquery = "$('#sub-secondary').load('".site_url('createplay/getSubSecondary')."?subcat='+this.value);";
```

you have not written script opening and closing tag for the jquery call. so response is creating dropdown menu but jquery call is treated as a html not as a script.

Second thing is when you create html element dynamically short methods like load, click etc does not work. So you have to write like below:

```
$jquery = "$(document).on('load', '#sub-secondary',('".site_url('createplay/getSubSecondary')."?subcat='+this.value);";
```

So please try above mentioned changes.